# R Plotly ScatterPolar chart - how to rotate labels individually?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to make a simple scatterpolar chart in R Plotly that has 60+ categorical labels on the radial axis.  Because there's so many labels, the default method of placing the labels results in them overlapping each other at the top and bottom of the chart.  I've tried setting layout.polar.angularaxis.tickangle to 90, -90, etc, but that rotates ALL labels by that amount.  Is there a way to either A) rotate each individual label by a specified value such that I can set some labels to -90 degrees, others to -45, others to 0, others to +45, etc... or B) leave the label rotations at 0 (as they are now), but dodge them a bit so they don't overlap at the top and bottom of the chart?  I think B would be easier and preferred, but not sure if either A or B are possible.

Here's a minimum reproducible example:

```
labs1 <- c("Red ", "Green ", "Blue ", "Yellow ", "Orange ", 
           "Purple ", "Pink ", "Black ", "White ", "Gray ")
labs2 <- c("Bookshelf", "Television", "Refridgerator", 
           "Toolbox", "Xylophone" , "Chromosome")
labs <- sample(paste0(rep(labs1, each = 6), rep(labs2, times = 10)), 60, replace = F)

df <- data.frame(Label = labs,
                 Radius = sample(0:100, 60, replace = F))

plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_trace(type = 'scatterpolar', mode = 'markers',
            r = ~Radius,
            theta = ~Label,
            fill = 'toself')
```

And here's the result:

[image: Scatterpolar with overlapping labels]

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since you asked, but I just ran across your question. I've got a workaround.

> If you'd like to duplicate the data I've used, I used `set.seed(35)` before calling the creation of `df`.

This uses the library `htmlwidgets` in addition to `plotly`.

I've added `margin` to the layout to account for label rotation. This may need to be modified. (For example, if you had really long labels, the margin would need to be larger.)

In the `onRender` call, I have several things happening.

- The function `detector`: checks for labels that have collided with each other
- The function `angler`: extracts the tick angle the label is associated with
- The function `quad`: identifies which quadrant of the circle it's working with, then rotates the text accordingly
- `lbls` is a node list of every label in the plot.
- The `for` loop rotates through `lbls`, sending every two labels to the function `detector`. If a collision is detected, the indicators are sent to the `angler` function (which calls the `quad` function).

It's not perfect, but it works.

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

plot_ly(df, type = 'scatterpolar', mode = 'markers',
        r = ~Radius, theta = ~Label, fill = 'toself') %>% 
  layout(margin = list(t = 75, r = 75, b = 75, l = 75)) %>% # make room for rotated labels
  onRender(
    "function(el, x) {
      function detector(r1, r2) {
        var r1 = r1.getBoundingClientRect(); /* catch associated real estate */
        var r2 = r2.getBoundingClientRect();
        return !(r2.left > r1.right ||       /* check for collisions */
                 r2.right < r1.left ||
                 r2.top > r1.bottom || 
                 r2.bottom < r1.top);
      }
      function angler(ind) {             /* get tick angle to rotate label */
        var par = lbls[ind].parentNode.parentNode.children[ind];
        var parAt = par.getAttribute('transform');
                                         /* send extracted angle to quad function*/
        quad(/(?<=rotate\\()[^)]*/.exec(parAt)[0], ind); /* using regex, after 'rotate(' -- except ')' */
      }
      function quad(ang, ind) {
        var ang = Math.abs(Number(ang)); /* make the angle a positive number */
        var gimmeXform = lbls[ind].getAttribute('transform'); /* extract values to modify */
        var xer = lbls[ind].getAttribute('x');  /* 3rd & 4th quad, ctrl rotation pt */
        var yer = lbls[ind].getAttribute('y');  /* 3rd & 4th quad, ctrl rotation pt */
        if(ang <= 90) {
          tang = ang * -.3;             /* rotate ang * -x, text-anchor: start */
          tanch = 'start';
        } else if (ang > 90 && ang <= 180) {
          tang = (180 - ang) * 0.3;       /* rotate ang * +x, text-anchor: end */
          tanch = 'end';
        } else if (ang > 180 && ang < 270) {
          tang = (ang - 180) * -.3;       /* rotate ang * -x, text-anchor: end */
          tang = '' + tang + ',' + xer + ',' + yer;    /* add rotation controls*/
          tanch = 'end';
        } else {
          tang = (360 - ang) * 0.3;     /* rotate ang * +x, text-anchor: start */
          tang = '' + tang + ',' + xer + ',' + yer;    /* add rotation controls*/
          tanch = 'start';
        } /* rotate text */
        lbls[ind].setAttribute('transform', gimmeXform + 'rotate(' + tang + ')');
        lbls[ind].setAttribute('text-anchor', tanch);
      }
      lbls = document.querySelectorAll('g.angularaxistick > text');
      inds = [];
      for(i = 0; i < lbls.length; i+=2) {
        if(detector(lbls[i], lbls[i + 1])) { /* if collision detected */
          angler(i);
          angler(i + 1);
        }
      }
    }"
  )
```

Whether you've plotted it with a ton of real estate:

[image]

Or very little real estate, it alters the labels:

[image]

FYI: if all of the labels overlap, it won't work.